# Doing Translate TranslateAnimation from just outside the screen on one side to just outside the screen on the other side

Tags: android, image, animation, screen-size

I have a ImageView called **myimage**.

I'm doing it **TranslateAnimation** from just outside the screen on one side to just outside the screen on the other side.

```
Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, -1500, 1500);
animation.setDuration(1000);
animation.setFillAfter(false);
myimage.startAnimation(animation);
```

Is there any way that lets me move it from just outside the screen on one side to just outside the screen on the other side regardless of any screen size ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have got it now.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
final float screen_width_half = metrics.widthPixels/2; 
final float distance = screen_width_half + 50;

//determine half screen width and add 50 to it to take it just a little outside the screen

Animation animation = 
new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, -distance, distance);
animation.setDuration(1000);
animation.setFillAfter(false);
myimage.startAnimation(animation);
```